# Freetype glyphs wrap when loaded into openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11, glfw, freetype

I'm trying to load TrueTypeFonts through freetype and display them using openGL and this is what I'm getting:

[image: Font application]

As you can see mostly it's fine but if you look closer each individual glyph seems to have some small incongruities around the borders. I noticed that these strange lines are actually carried over pixels from the other side. Look at the 'T' and 'h' in particular where you can see small bars corresponding with the opposite side of the texture. This happens with different fonts as well. Here is the code responsible for copying the glyph bitmap buffer into openGL:

```
    void load(FT_GlyphSlot glyphSlot, double loadedHeight){
        this->loadedHeight = loadedHeight;
        int width = glyphSlot->bitmap.width;
        int height = glyphSlot->bitmap.rows;

        sizeRatios = Vector2D(width / loadedHeight, height / loadedHeight);
        offsetRatios = Vector2D(glyphSlot->bitmap_left / loadedHeight, glyphSlot->metrics.horiBearingY / loadedHeight);
        advanceRatios = Vector2D((glyphSlot->advance.x >> 6) / loadedHeight, (glyphSlot->advance.y >> 6) / loadedHeight);

        std::cout << width << ", " << height << std::endl;

        GLubyte * textureData = new GLubyte[width * height * 4];

        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                    textureData[(x + y * width) * 4 + i] = glyphSlot->bitmap.buffer[x + width * y];
                }
            }
        }

        texture.bind();
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        texture.load(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, glyphSlot->bitmap.width, glyphSlot->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
        // glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        delete [] textureData;
    }
```

The size of the font face is set elsewhere and passed into this method along with the glyph slot that I want to load. The texture object is just a class that creates a texture handle and keeps track of it, load just passes the parameters directly into glTexImage2D().

I've tried shifting the pixels by one using modulus rotation and it worked vertically but not horizontally. I have also tried loading the texture by passing the buffer directly into load by changing the format to GL_RED as described [here](http://www.gedge.ca/dev/2013/12/08/opengl-text-rendering-with-freetype/) but the problem doesn't go away, so I think that maybe it might even be a flaw in freetype?

I wonder is there is some basic element of texture loading that I do not understand.

If you need some additional source code to understand what is wrong please ask.

Comment: To optimize, maybe You should generate all glyphs earlier, put it onto separate texture (with given offset on x and y axes), then transfer single texture to card and paint with parts of bigger texture. Thanks to this, You will have to generate bitmaps only once, and thanks to given non-zero offsets textures won't bleed. Otherwise, @genpfault answer should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to load every glyph in a face and I wanted to be unicode friendly so decided to do loading on a when-necessary basis. There is a font class that calls the load function only if the character hasn't already been loaded and the size previously loaded is too small for the requested draw size. If this proves too inefficient later I will swap it but right now I want to remain flexible in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S`/`GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` default to `GL_REPEAT`.

Use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` instead.